# Yum, Redhat - Why am I getting 'Name collision between …' errors and how can I fix this?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

Every time I try to launch 'yum' I get the following errors:

```
Name collision between kterm kterm
Name collision between kterm-color kterm-color
Name collision between xterm-nic xterm-nic
Name collision between xterm1 xterm1
Name collision between color_xterm color_xterm
Name collision between xterm-color xterm-color
Name collision between gnome-rh62 gnome-rh62
Name collision between gnome-rh72 gnome-rh72
Name collision between gnome-rh80 gnome-rh80
Name collision between gnome-rh90 gnome-rh90
Name collision between gnome-fc5 gnome-fc5
Name collision between gnome gnome
Name collision between gnome-256color gnome-256color
Name collision between kvt kvt
Name collision between konsole-base konsole-base
Name collision between konsole-linux konsole-linux
Name collision between konsole-solaris konsole-solaris
Name collision between konsole-xf3x konsole-xf3x
Name collision between konsole-xf4x konsole-xf4x
Name collision between konsole-vt100 konsole-vt100
Name collision between konsole-vt420pc konsole-vt420pc
Name collision between konsole-16color konsole-16color
Name collision between konsole konsole
Name collision between mlterm mlterm
Name collision between rxvt-basic rxvt-basic
Name collision between rxvt+pcfkeys rxvt+pcfkeys
Name collision between rxvt rxvt
Name collision between rxvt-color rxvt-color
Name collision between rxvt-256color rxvt-256color
Name collision between rxvt-xpm rxvt-xpm
Name collision between rxvt-cygwin rxvt-cygwin
Name collision between rxvt-cygwin-native rxvt-cygwin-native
Name collision between rxvt-16color rxvt-16color
Name collision between rxvt-unicode rxvt-unicode
Name collision between Eterm Eterm
Name collision between xtermm xtermm
Name collision between xtermc xtermc
Name collision between xterm-pcolor xterm-pcolor
....
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Are you running `yum` in a GNU Screen session? Can you provide `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: no, i can't run that. -> [root@lts5srv1 site-packages]# ~/.bashrc
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
And i'm logged in as root on centOS.

Comment: `cat ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: i get this: # .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=/root/epd-5.1.0/bin:${PATH}

Comment: You haven't answered my first question.

Comment: I'm sory, the response is no, for the first qst ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-installed a new version of Python, changed some environment variables and it worked.
Follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320143/python-importerror-no-module-named-os) link to see, what i did to solve the problems in my case. The problem at the "solution link" was another, but following the steps there solves also the problem described in this page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to temporary (re)move all *.repo from /etc/yum.repos.d/ to /tmp/ and after that try "yum clean all", if that solves that then try to look at those files and move them back one by one and see when problem start occurring again.

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
repo id                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                                         status
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                  Adobe Systems Incorporated                                                                                                            2
epel                                                                                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                                    7,720
google-chrome                                                                                       google-chrome                                                                                                                         3
google-talkplugin                                                                                   google-talkplugin                                                                                                                     1
sl                                                                                                  Scientific Linux 6.1 - x86_64                                                                                                     6,251
sl-security                                                                                         Scientific Linux 6.1 - x86_64 - security updates                                                                                  1,954
repolist: 15,931
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo /tmp/
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
repolist: 0
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: emm, i have some "Name collision... " when i try to run "yum clean all" !!!

Comment: did you remove everything from /etc/yum.repos.d?

Comment: yes, i've removed all the folder

Comment: should i remove also : /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/ ??

Comment: please run "yum repolist" and "yum list" and show output

Comment: but, the output is allways the same !!

Comment: I can't troubleshoot if you unwilling to cooperate. I asked you to make a change and show me output (output should be somewhat different since we made some change).

Comment: [root@lts5srv1 yum]# yum repolist  ---> 
Name collision between dumb dumb
Name collision between unknown unknown
Name collision between lpr lpr
Name collision between glasstty glasstty
Name collision between vanilla vanilla
Name collision between ansi+local1 ansi+local1
Name collision between ansi+local ansi+local
Name collision between ansi+tabs ansi+tabs
Name collision between ansi+inittabs ansi+inittabs
Name collision between ansi+erase ansi+erase
Name collision between ansi+rca ansi+rca
Name collision between ansi+cup ansi+cup

Comment: let me see your "ll /etc/yum/*"

Comment: [root@lts5srv1 yum]# ls /etc/yum/*
rhnplugin.conf  security.con

Comment: try using "yum --debuglevel=10" and show the output

Comment: [root@lts5srv1 hello]# yum --debuglevel=10  ---> 
Name collision between dumb dumb
Name collision between unknown unknown
Name collision between lpr lpr
Name collision between glasstty glasstty
Name collision between vanilla vanilla
Name collision between ansi+local1 ansi+local1
Name collision between ansi+local ansi+local
Name collision between ansi+tabs ansi+tabs
Name collision between ansi+inittabs ansi+inittabs
Name collision between ansi+erase ansi+erase
Name collision between ansi+rca ansi+rca
Name collision between ansi+cup ansi+cup

Comment: I dont think your "yum" is original yum, it seems like every command that we do returns same thing. do "rpm -q yum" and then "which yum", "file `which yum`", alias | grep yum